# Why is this returning a "Not Found" with PHP and cURL?

Tags: php, curl, header, xss

My script works with all other links I tried, and i get the same response with cURL also (and this is a lot smaller, so I like this code):

```
<?php
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    $header = get_headers($url,1);
    print_r($header);
    function get_url($u,$h){
        if(preg_match('/200/',$h[0])){
            echo file_get_contents($u);
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/301/',$h[0])){
            $nh = get_headers($h['Location']);
            get_url($h['Location'],$nh);
        }
    }
    get_url($url,$header);
?>
```

But for:
http://www.anthropologie.com/anthro/catalog/productdetail.jsp?subCategoryId=HOME-TABLETOP-UTENSILS&id=78110&catId=HOME-TABLETOP&pushId=HOME-TABLETOP&popId=HOME&sortProperties=&navCount=355&navAction=top&fromCategoryPage=true&selectedProductSize=&selectedProductSize1=&color=sil&colorName=SILVER&isProduct=true&isBigImage=&templateType=

And:
http://www.urbanoutfitters.com/urban/catalog/productdetail.jsp?itemdescription=true&itemCount=80&startValue=1&selectedProductColor=&sortby=&id=14135412&parentid=A_FURN_BATH&sortProperties=+subCategoryPosition,&navCount=56&navAction=poppushpush&color=&pushId=A_FURN_BATH&popId=A_DECORATE&prepushId=&selectedProductSize=

(and all Anthropologie product links). I'm assuming other sites I have no yet found act this way also. Here is my header response:

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [Server] => Apache
    [X-Powered-By] => Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.2.0.GA_CP05 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_4_2_0_GA_CP05 date=200810231548)/JBossWeb-2.0
    [X-ATG-Version] => version=RENTLUFEQyxBVEdQbGF0Zm9ybS85LjFwMSxBREMgWyBEUFNMaWNlbnNlLzAgIF0=
    [Content-Type] => text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
    [Date] => Sat, 24 Jul 2010 23:47:47 GMT
    [Content-Length] => 21669
    [Connection] => keep-alive
    [Set-Cookie] => Array
        (
            [0] => JSESSIONID=65CA111ADBF267A3B405C69A325576F8.app46-node2; Path=/
            [1] => visitCount=1; Expires=Fri, 29-May-2026 00:41:07 GMT; Path=/
            [2] => UOCCII:=; Expires=Mon, 23-Aug-2010 23:47:47 GMT; Path=/
            [3] => LastVisited=2010-07-24; Expires=Fri, 29-May-2026 00:41:07 GMT; Path=/
        )

)
```

I'm guessing maybe it has to do with the cookies? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Install [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and see what is actually being sent.

You can also try setting your user-agent to a real browser. Sometimes sites try to prevent scraping by checking this.

Comment: I did in my cURL code. I set a browser and a referrer and im on Linux and Mac... no Windows :\

Comment: I am sure there is a mac equivalent out there. Doing this kind of work without being able to see the raw data going back and forth is working blind.